# Invalid content error on compression:extract

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am attempting to use the zip-extract method in a foreach loop to unzip several files. When I attempt to deploy the project the following error is returned:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'compression:extract'. One of >'{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, >"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, >"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

The actual code is:

```
<compression:extract doc:name="Extract" doc:id="9119d722-95eb-4aee-a734-50e2a2825449" >
    <set-payload value="#[payload]" />
    <compression:extractor >
        <compression:zip-extractor />
    </compression:extractor>
</compression:extract>
```

I have not been able to find anything online that would point towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like accidentally a `<set-payload>` was put inside the `<compression:extract>` element. Also it doesn't make sense at all because it puts the payload as the payload, which it is already is. Just remove that line.

Maybe the intention was to use `<compression-compressed>`?

Example:

```
<compression:extract>
    <compression:compressed>#[payload]</compression:compressed> 
    <compression:extractor>
        <compression:zip-extractor/> 
    </compression:extractor>
</compression:extract>
```

[payload is already the default](https://docs.mulesoft.com/compression-module/2.0/#extract-operation), so it is not needed.

Comment: The "set-payload" line was added based on another answer from the site. Removing that line didn't help. It still won't deploy and the same error was returned.

Comment: The issue is also it is not recognizing compression-extract. Did you add the compression module dependency to the pom and the namespace to the Mule XML?

Comment: Yes!!! I would have sworn that I had added that dependency, but it was not / no longer there. I added that to the pom file and it depoys. Thanks for you help!